# Magento 2 translation for vendor module

Tags: magento, magento2

So I have vednor module example (vendor/companyx/modulex/) and If I put my local translation file (sl_SI.csv) info vendor translation folder (vendor/companyx/modulex/i18n/) translations are working but this is not the right way to do it as module will get udpated and translations will be lost.

I don't want to put all translations into one file (app/i18n/Mymodule/sl_SI/sl_SI.csv) as it would be hard to manage different module translations etx.

When in tried different options translations were not working like:

app/code/Companyx/Modulex/i18n/sl_SI.csv

app/i18n/Companyx/Modulex/sl_SI.csv

Is there any other way?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to create a file app/code/<Your_Vendor>/ModulexExtend/i18n/sl_SI.csv
then use this in your file:

```
"add to cart", "add to bag", module, Companyx_Modulex
```

or try to create a file in theme: app/design/frontend/<your_vendor_name>/<your_theme_name>/Companyx/Modulex/i18n/sl_SI.csv

Comment: Thank you for answer. First option is hard to mantain when having a lot of modules. Second one I don't think tranlsations will work for admin in that case?